# Does CDATA preserve all escaped character sequences in XML?

Tags: xml, cdata

Do XML parsers translate escaped characters such as `&#x0d;` and `&#x0a;` even when they occur in CDATA?

I was confused by the answer to this question: [Does the XML specification states that parser need to convert \n\r to \n always, even when \n\r appears in a CDATA section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817378/does-the-xml-specification-states-that-parser-need-to-convert-n-r-to-n-always)

...because it quotes from the spec saying that sequences like `#xD #xA` are replaced with a single '\n' character, but then goes on to say that using `&#xD;` and `&#xA;` is a reliable way to preserve the characters. Is the semi-colon significant? (I don't have time to study the XML spec)

Also, I am aware that the 2 characters above are carriage return and line feed, and that they are normalized to just line feed by XML parsers - if the rules for what happens inside CDATA for line breaks is different to escaped sequences in general, then I hereby ask both questions!

Thanks,
rp

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The parser does not touch **anything** in a CDATA section.

The semicolon does not make a difference.

Comment: This is incorrect. Newlines in CDATA are normalized (https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends). "before parsing" means that the normalization occurs without knowing if the content is CDATA or not.